# Variable sized char[] - Is it OK?

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, size, iso

forgive me if this is stupid but I'm newer to C/C++.

In the socket library I'm creating, my ClientSocket::recv(int bufsize) function uses 'bufsize' to initialize a char[] array to read into from the C socket. The code, given you compile with G++, works fine.

The issue I am having is that some people that are compiling my code are getting the following error:  `socket.cxx||In member function ‘std::string ClientSocket::recv(int)’:|
socket.cxx|269|error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘buffer’|`

Now, from what I've read on this forum is that Microsoft only supports C89, whereas GCC supports C99 in which variable-sized arrays are acceptable. Also on that thread, they suggested using _alloca() - The problem is, that supports only up to 1mb. I'd rather there not be a limit.

If that is the only possible way to make it cross-compilable with GCC/MSVC++, I guess I'll have to live with it. It'd be nice to know a alternative though. Would something like malloc() work? (never used it before, so I don't know) If so, could you please tell me how to use it or link to a tutorial/docs? Thanks!

P.S.: Here's the code for my recv() function:

```
std::string ClientSocket::recv(int bufsize) {

    // isConnected() is a ClientSocket function
    if (!isConnected()) throw SocketException("Not connected.");

    char buffer[bufsize+1];

    // I did this because sometimes it was returning partial garbage :\
    memset(buffer, 0, bufsize);

    // the :: prefix means to call the recv() from the header files instead of ClientSocket::recv()
    int ret = ::recv(sockfd, buffer, bufsize-1, 0);

    if (ret < 0) {
        switch(errno) {
            case ECONNREFUSED:
                throw SocketException("Connection refused on recover.");
                break;
            case ENOTCONN:
                throw SocketException("Not connected.");
                break;
            default:
                throw SocketException("Unknown error reading socket.");
                break;
        }
    } else if (ret == 0) {
        // we got disconnected, return empty string. (connected is a protected variable of ClientSocket)
        connected = false;
        return "";
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

EDIT: As per recommendations, I plan to use  either `vector buffer(bufsize+1, 0); ... recv(sockfd, &buffer[0], bufsize, 0); ... return &buffer[0];` OR `char *buffer = new char[bufsize + 1]; memset(buffer, 0, bufsize); ... recv(sockfd, buffer, bufsize, 0); ... string tmp = buffer; delete [] buffer; return string(tmp);` - Still installing MSVC++ in order to test it, but I believe it will work. THANK YOU SO MUCH! StackOverflow ROCKS!

Comment: I could be off base here, but do you need more than 1 megabyte buffer for socket io?

Comment: Good point. Usually I use 1024 bytes, but I am going to be distributing this as a library and I would not enjoy having to limit it in any way.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of a library to funnel behavior into defined paths (which is a form of imposing limits?) Personally, I say reasonable limits aren't a problem at all. And developers can work around reasonable limits very very easily. If it ends up being a problem, they will tell you (oh, boy oh boy they will tell you!)

Comment: You're not receiving the whole incoming buffer, and you're allocating one more byte but you're not setting that extra byte; you probably want to write buffer[ret] = 0; return buffer; instead.

Comment: @Neil - Thanks, I'll do that. :)  @glowcoder - I really want this to act like python's socket library, which afaik has no limit on recv().

Comment: Make sure that if you allocate memory with `foo = new char[...]` to later free it again not with `delete foo` but with `delete [] foo`. Do not forget the `[]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

g++ allows C99 Variable Length Arrays in C++ as a language extension.

they're not supported by standard C++.

in C++ use a `std::vector` or `std::string`.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: But the problem is that I can't pass a vector to the ::recv(sockfd, buffer, bufsize-1, 0);
 of the C socket. AFAIK, it must be a char*... Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @FurryHead: If (and only if) you use `std::vector<char> buffer( buffsize + 1, 0 );` you can call `recv(sockfd, &buffer[ 0 ], bufsize, 0);` and skip the call to `memset`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be std::vector<char*> ... ? vector<char> would be like a list of chars, vector<char*> would be a list of pointers to char[]s wouldn't it? (but I see what you're saying now) That would indeed be convenient, as there wouldn't be a call to memset and no dealing with deleting stuff. Thanks!@

Comment: @FurryHead: `char buffer[]` is a list of chars and `vector<char>` is it's C++ stdlib equivalent.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the clarification, when you put: std::vector<char> buffer(bufsize+1); recv(sockfd, &buffer[0], bufsize, 0);  it appears you're passing a char instead of a char[].

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

`char * buffer = new char[bufsize + 1];`

Comment: That is going to be twice as slow. And twice the strain on the heap manager.

Comment: I don't currently have MSVC++, but I will try it as soon as it gets installed.

Comment: @Fyodor, the performance impact is very minimal; I doubt it's noticeable.

Comment: Exactly how slow? A difference of 0.00001ms? or a whole second? If it's a ridiculously small amount, I don't care - If I cared about speed, I wouldn't be making a C++ wrapper class on top of C sockets ;) EDIT: Thanks @myrkos, entered my comment before I saw yours.

Comment: @Fyodor 1) [citation needed] 2) Even so, allocation is... really really fast! So even if you make something really really fast take twice as long, it's still... really really fast!

Comment: @glowcoder nicely put. Though, _technically_, something 'really really' fast taking twice as long would only be 'really' fast ;) (just nitpicking, hehe)

Comment: @FurryHead depends on the definition of really, now doesn't it? What if I would consider something "really fast" to be 10x faster than "fast", where each really is 10x faster? So maybe it would only be "eally really fast" or something? :-)

Comment: ROFL - Truly, nicely put. You got me stumped there ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a simple buffer class that wrapped a `char *` to deal with this. It would use `new` to allocate the buffer. I believe it is also possible to use a `vector` and still be standards compliant. But I'm not completely sure how to go about it in the recommended way.

Comment: I would gladly use a vector<char>, but the recv() function in the standard berkley c socket library takes a char* as a argument - a wrapper class wouldn't work, would it? It has to be passed as a char*

Comment: @FurryHead: The wrapper class would have a function that return its inner `char *`. It's job would be to manage newing and deleting the `char *` at the appropriate times. And this is basically what you'd have to do with the `vector` as well. Pass in something like `&vec[0]` into `recv`.

Comment: Aaahh, I see. Have the allocator in the constructor, a function to return it's char*, and the delete call in the destructor? That would be very interesting to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you don't even need to use memset, if you're on gcc or g++ 
you can actually assign it all zeros using normal aggregation
on the char type, consider this:

```
char * buffer[bufsize+1] = {0};
```

this code will work in gcc/g++ only because gcc
allows variable sized arrays on the stack.

Your only other option is to use:

```
char * buffer = new char[bufsize+1];
// and assign it zeros with std::fill
std::fill(buffer, buffer+bufsize+1, 0);
```

Comment: also if you use a vector you can pass the vector by using &(*vectorname.begin())